# using multiple variables in plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use plyr but have difficulties in using several variables. 
Here an example.

```
    df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
    Firm Foreign SME Turnover
A1       N   Y      200
A2       N   N     1000
A3       Y   Y      100
A1       N   N      500
A2       Y   Y      200
A3       Y   Y     1000
A1       Y   N      200
A2       N   N     1000
A2       N   Y      100
A2       N   Y      200  ")
```

I am trying to create a table which summarize the Turnover on the two variables. 
Basically combining the following codes

```
t1 <- ddply(df, c('Firm', 'Foreign'), summarise, 
        BudgetForeign    = sum(Turnover, na.rm = TRUE))

t2 <- ddply(df, c('Firm', 'SME'), summarise, 
        BudgetSME    = sum(Turnover, na.rm = TRUE))
```

with following results

```
res <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Firm          A1   A2   A3  
BudgetForeign 200  200 1100
BudgetSME     200  500 1100")
res
```

How can I achieve this without doing multiple operations and subset and combine afterwards ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you only want the values where Foreign or SME are `'Y'`... if that's the case.  I would use  `melt` and `dcast` from the `reshape2` package rather than `plyr`.

```
df.m <- melt(df, id.var=c('Firm', 'Turnover'))

dcast(df.m[df.m$value=='Y',], variable ~ Firm, value.var='Turnover', fun.aggregate=sum)

  variable  A1  A2   A3
1  Foreign 200 200 1100
2      SME 200 500 1100
```

If you want to see the differences between `Y` and `N` also you can add them to the formula in `dcast`:

```
> dcast(df.m, variable + value ~ Firm, value.var='Turnover', fun.aggregate=sum)
  variable value  A1   A2   A3
1  Foreign     N 700 2300    0
2  Foreign     Y 200  200 1100
3      SME     N 700 2000    0
4      SME     Y 200  500 1100
>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. At least I know where to start. I have one question though. How will it work I want different values for Foreign and SME let's say "Y" and "N" respectively.

Comment: @user1043144 Not sure I understand.  You could add it to the formula in `dcast` and remove it from the `df.m[]`. see my edits.

Comment: thanks Justin. library(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.var=c('Firm', 'Turnover'))

x <- dcast(df.m, variable + value ~ Firm, value.var='Turnover', fun.aggregate=sum)


res <- rbind(
             BudgetForeign = subset(x, variable == 'Foreign' & value == 'Y'),
             BudgetSME = subset(x, variable == 'SME' & value == 'Y')
             )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Justin. 
From your answer, the following code should solve my problem.

```
library(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.var=c('Firm', 'Turnover'))

x <- dcast(df.m, variable + value ~ Firm, value.var='Turnover', fun.aggregate=sum)


res <- rbind(
         BudgetForeign = subset(x, variable == 'Foreign' & value == 'Y'),
         BudgetSME = subset(x, variable == 'SME' & value == 'Y')
         )
res
```

Comment: You can do that without the `rbind` step... subset like I did in my first example and use the formula I used in my second example.  `res <- dcast(df.m[df.m$value=='Y',], variable + value ~ Firm, value.var='Turnover', fun.aggregate=sum)`.  Then if you want to name the rows go ahead.  `row.names(res) <- c('BudgetForeign', 'BudgetSME')`